# High memory usage nginx (reverse proxy) on new vps

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy, centos7

I recently set up a new vps (Cent OS7) with custombuild 2.0, Apache 2.4 with nginx reverse proxy, php-fpm 5.6 (and 7), mpm worker, MariaDB 10.1, mod_security and csf.

For some reason Nginx uses 675mb of memory (http://prntscr.com/91bu6t) with only 1 (1mb) website on the server and 1 light (300mb) website which consits mostly of pictures.
When i restart nginx the memory usage is still about 175mb after some time, back to +/- 675mb again. 
I don't think this is normal. The config files seem ok.
And I don't see much in the nginx logs, except these lines returning:

> 2015/11/10 21:20:41 [notice] 24971#0: ModSecurity for nginx
>   (STABLE)/2.9.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured. 2015/11/10
>   21:20:41 [notice] 24971#0: ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.2";
>   loaded version="1.5.2" 2015/11/10 21:20:41 [notice] 24971#0:
>   ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.20 "; loaded version="8.20
>   2011-10-21" 2015/11/10 21:20:41 [notice] 24971#0: ModSecurity: LIBXML
>   compiled version="2.9.2" 2015/11/10 21:20:41 [notice] 24971#0:
>   ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set
>   SecStatusEngine to On.

Are these lines indicating an issue? (Google doesn't make me much wiser..)

And mainly, why is the nginx memory usage so high with so little going on the server? What to do about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell based on just the output of your admin panel but it could be that the server / nginx is caching a lot of memory to improve performance. If you have shell access, you can see more details using for example the `top` command.

If caching is the case, there is nothing wrong with that, it just optimizes your memory use versus disk use.

Comment: I have shall access. I'm running top. What should i look for?
And the notices are nothing to worry about?

Comment: @Peps The messages about ModSecurity seem normal. About `top`, the `mem` (4th?) line shows you exactly what is being used, what is free and how much is cached.

Comment: It shows: 
top - 14:52:53 up  2:45,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 181 total,   1 running, 180 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3882636 total,  2558456 free,   438924 used,   885256 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1048572 total,  1048572 free,        0 used.  3234320 avail Mem

Comment: @Peps Assuming that the memory numbers have a `k` behind them, you can see that in total only about 400Mb is used by the whole server / all processes together. More than 800Mb is cached and that is not really used; it is available when needed but it already has things loaded that you are probably going to use. I would guess that that number will increase even more over time, optimizing performance of the server.

Comment: Is 0,98gb memory usage also still "normal"? See http://prntscr.com/93f9na  Server hasn't changed since i opened this question.

Comment: @Peps In my experience it just fills up all available memory with cache, no matter how much you have, so you might hardly use anything, but the memory use is optimized for performance.